# GitShell, how can I not type the username and passwords?

Tags: git, github

[image]

Open the CMD, and I should type the password and usename?
In the GitShell opened by shortcut, I don't need to type the username and password.

Related is here:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/209014/how-can-i-convert-gitshells-commands-into-an-bat-file

Is this useful, I cannot make it take effect now?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031214/git-how-to-use-netrc-file-on-windows-to-save-user-and-password

Comment: Try pushing via ssh link (after creating an ssh key https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)

Comment: @chedy2149 Fine, today it's ok now, I'm not sure which method makes it works well, wish it'll good as always.